# Vuejs data in the array you refreshed page is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What I want to do is to keep the objects in the series permanently, even if the page is refreshed. Whenever I delete it, I want the data to be deleted in the series. How can I do that?

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data(){
       return {  
           item: []
       }
   },
   methods: {
      addToCart: function(value){
         // This way, I can keep all the data in the item directory. But it is deleted when the page is refreshed.
         this.item.push(value);
      }
   }
})
```

is the name of the empty array product

My goal is to keep the selected products permanently in the series, and even if the page is refreshed, I want to make the data in the series permanent and process this information as I want.

Comment: did you try `localStorage` ?

Comment: use a backend that saves it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do that if you store your data to the `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or `cookies` otherwise all the data will be eliminated on the refresh.

Here is the official documentation from [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html) on how to store data on the client-side.
Basically instead of pushing the data to a variable, you have to save it on the client-side, let's say on `localStorage` something like the code below:

```
addToCart: function(value){
   const cart = localStorage.getItem('cart');
   cart.push(value);
   localStorage.setItem('cart', cart);
}
```

Be careful though, `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, and `cookies` have some differences not only on their API but on their use as well, check this out for [more](https://scotch.io/@PratyushB/local-storage-vs-session-storage-vs-cookie)

Comment: Thank you for help me ;)